# Select particular fields from a database using a checkbox in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select particular fields from a database using a checkbox in PHP.
My code is:

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1' class='tabtext'>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders");
$numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<table>\n<tr>";

for ($i=0; $i < $numfields; $i++) // Header
{ 
    echo '<th>'.mysql_field_name($result, $i).'</th>'; 
    echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="checkbox[]" value="false"/></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="true"/></td></tr>';

    $checkbox[$i] = isset($_POST['checkbox'][$i]) ? true : false;
    if(isset($checkbox))
    {
        foreach($checkbox as $value)
        {
            echo $value."<br>"; //it will print the value of your checkbox that you checked
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will give you better results.

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1' class='tabtext'>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);

// show headers
echo '<thead><tr>';
for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
    $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
    echo '<th><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[' . $field_name . ']" value="1"/> ' . $field_name . '</label></th>';
}
echo '</tr></thead>';

echo '<tbody>';
for ($row = 0; $row < $numrows; $row++) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
        $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
        if (isset($_POST['checkbox'][$field_name])) {
            echo '<td>' . $data[$field_name] . '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```